# Different jars, same stuff

Tags: java, build, jar, executable-jar

My question is not about CI systems but here is a little history for context.

My CI system produces a jar but intermittently the jar file doesn't work (the bad one can't find various beans). The current working theory is that jars built on the CI-agent sometimes produce bad jars and running the CI process again randomly fixes the problem. The 2 systems are running the same versions of java/etc and the jar is a totally self contained Spring Application with all it's configuration and dependant jars contained within.

I have a good jar and a bad jar. Their md5 is different but when I unzip them they produce exactly the same contents (according to unix-diff/kdiff3).

So the question is what is making the difference in the jar that is not reflected in different files? How can I confirm what that difference is? Is the jar packer just a zipper or does it do other things as well? Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What makes a jar "bad?"  Is it just about the mismatched md5?

Comment: Are you using the `-b` or `-w` or `-i` options with unix-diff?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The jar is a Spring Application with the deps all bundled together. The application boots properly with the "good" jar but fails to start with the "bad" jar. The error message talks about classes being undefined and beans not being defined. I used `diff -r` but I'll try again with those suggested switches.

Comment: Tried those options. I even tried `-s` (report when identical) and made sure that it returned the same number of files as I got from `find`. Stumped!